# hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character: still encounter problem after replace \0 with ""

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have a problem with my code.
I used ASP.NET with Visual Studio 2010.

When i retrieve a data from database to a datatable in a webservice, some column give me a empty string data. This caused some problem with the XML retrieved and displayed. I try to put a `Replace ("","")` to replace `\0\0\0`. THis one can solve the problem. But now the problem is, the orginal data still shown in the XML. The original data is the one with `\0\0`.Before replace, the XML field is `<VNDPNO></VNDPNO>` and after replace become `<VNDPNO />`.

My question is, how to hide the original data.
I dont want the original data when i call it
It keep showing in the web browser in `<diffgr:before>`.

My source code is :

```
public DataTable GetItmSupDtls(string companycode, string itemCode, 
                               string itemMajor, string itemMinor)
{
    DataTable dsItmSupDtls;
    //DataSet dsItmSupDtls = new DataSet();
    IDBManager dbManager = new DBManager(DataProvider.SqlServer);
    dbManager.ConnectionString = _connString;
    try
    {
        dbManager.Open();
        dbManager.CreateParameters(4);
        dbManager.AddParameters(0, "@COYCDE", (object)companycode);
        dbManager.AddParameters(1, "@ITMCDE", (object)itemCode);
        dbManager.AddParameters(2, "@ITMMAJ", (object)itemMajor);
        dbManager.AddParameters(3, "@ITMMIN", (object)itemMinor);
        dsItmSupDtls = dbManager.ExecuteDataSet(
            CommandType.StoredProcedure, 
            Utilities.DatabaseName("DBPurchase") + ".dbo.ITMSUPINFO_STKBALENQUIRY"
        ).Tables[0];
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    finally
    {
        dbManager.Dispose();
    }

    DataTable result = dsItmSupDtls.Clone();

    foreach (DataRow dtRow in dsItmSupDtls.Rows)
    {
        dtRow["VNDPNO"] = 
            dtRow["VNDPNO"].ToString().Replace("\0", ""); //"A"; //
        result.ImportRow(dtRow);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Kindly give me some comment and suggestion.

Many thanks..

Comment: There's a few things I'm not quite getting here. For a start, why is `Replace("", "")` meant to do anything? For a second, what is the issue with `<VNDPNO></VNDPNO>` becoming `<VNDPNO />`? - those are semantically equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

The way your information is being transfered is through a diffgram.  I think the history will come with it if you use ImportRow instead of InsertRow.  Since InsertRow can be more expensive with a lot of rows you may want to only use ImportRow when the value contained a null.

Comment: There is nothing to stop a null character being sent with HTTP payload (the entity is defined as a series of octets, not characters, and a 0x00 octet is fine - otherwise a lot of images couldn't be sent), but U+0000 cannot be in XML data, whether directly or as a character entity (even XML1.1 which loosens the restrictions on characters used cannot allow U+0000 to be contained), so putting &#x0000; into an XML document makes it not well-formed.

Comment: Yes you're correct, I misspoke thanks for catching it. I will edit the response.